# Можно ли из кода C++ вызвать функцию на Swift?

Tags: c++, swift

При разработке под iphone на `Swifte` возникла необходимость вызвать функцию на `C++`. С этой задачей легко справились. Но внутри функции на `С++` появилась необходимость дёрнуть функцию из `Swifta`.

**Вопрос:** Можно ли в принципе вызвать из `C++` функцию на `Swifte`? Если да - то как это сделать? Если невозможно, то какие принципиальные, неприодолимые ограничения?

Comment: Странно что ответов нет. 1)Если swift поддерживает COM(ActiveX) то пульнув интерфейс в с++ у вас сразу связь. 2)На крайний случай -  связь можно сделать любыми кросс-процессовыми штуками, т.е. pipe, socket и другие.

Comment: @nick_n_a а может вы с гитхабом дружите, дадите ссылочку?